# Android - getSharedPreferences cannot Resolve

Tags: javascript, android

Hello i have getSharedPreferences cannot resolve, i search much answers but anything resolve this.
how to implement getSharedPreferences in onclick iside ViewHolder?

MyHolder.class

```js
 public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView nametxt;
    ImageView img;
    TextView url;
    TextView channel;
    Context c;


    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);


        nametxt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        img= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
        url= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.urltxt);
        channel= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channel);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), VideoPlayerActivity.class);
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                String user = prefs.getString("user", "");

                String urls= url.getText().toString()+user+user+channel.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("urls", urls);


                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });



    }




}
```

Comment: use `context.getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this :-

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to this :-

```
SharedPreferences prefs = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: How  can you use `getActivity` method in a `ViewHolder` subclass - don't you mean `v.getContext()`?

Comment: I change, but have the error cannot resolve getActivity

Comment: @KevinDanielGómezHalyburton read new answer from akhilesh0707, it has correct solution, as per my comment.

Comment: @MarkKeen I'm sorry! My bad. The answers involving `v.getContext()` are correct.

Comment: I have always used the view holder as an inner class of my adapter. `Adapter` has the `getActivity()` method - so I implicitly wrote that for my answer. But I should have double checked before posting. Thank you for the clarification @MarkKeen

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Try this using `context`, you can get `context` from your view which is `v`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access shared preferences from context and you have access to context as `v.getContext`

Answer (score 0):

this can also work.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```